# Activity doesn't start from two different ones but from only one

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-anr-dialog

I have several activities in my app. I'd like to start an activity say A from other two separate ones, B and C.
From B A starts good, from C it alerts me with ANR advise. Cosidering that:

```
  1. Activities are all declared in the Manifest
  2. There are no incoerent castings
```

And this is the activity A that must be opened:

package com.wikibuyers.aforismi;

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
 import java.io.Writer;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
 import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
 import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
 import android.view.animation.Animation;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageButton;
 import android.widget.Toast;


public class ElencoAforismiActivity extends Activity{

  public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.provacomunicazionefraactivity.MESSAGE";

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.elecoalfabeticoautori);

  Button bottoneA = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
  Button bottoneB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
  Button bottoneC = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
  [...]
        Button bottoneX = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonX);
  Button bottoneY = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonY);
  Button bottoneZ = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonZ);
  ImageButton Preferiti = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonPreferiti);


  bottoneA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonA ); 
             Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);// LAMPEGGIO BOTTONE 1
              anim.setDuration(20); //SI PUò CONTROLLARE LA DURATA DEL LAMPEGGIO CON QUESTO PARAMETRO
              anim.setStartOffset(20);
              anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
              myButton.startAnimation(anim);
              anim.setRepeatCount(5);  
                 String message = "A" ;    

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LetteraElencoSelezionataActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                   startActivity(i);  
        }
    });

  bottoneB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonB ); 
             Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);// LAMPEGGIO BOTTONE 1
              anim.setDuration(20); //SI PUò CONTROLLARE LA DURATA DEL LAMPEGGIO CON QUESTO PARAMETRO
              anim.setStartOffset(20);
              anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
              myButton.startAnimation(anim);
              anim.setRepeatCount(5);  
         String message = "B" ;    

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LetteraElencoSelezionataActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
           startActivity(i);  
        }
    });

  bottoneC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonC ); 
             Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);// LAMPEGGIO BOTTONE 1

              anim.setDuration(20); //SI PUò CONTROLLARE LA DURATA DEL LAMPEGGIO CON QUESTO PARAMETRO
              anim.setStartOffset(20);
              anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
              myButton.startAnimation(anim);

              anim.setRepeatCount(5);  

              String message = "C" ;    

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LetteraElencoSelezionataActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                   startActivity(i);  
        }
    });


 [...omissis]

  Preferiti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {ImageButton myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonPreferiti ); 
             Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);// LAMPEGGIO BOTTONE 1
              anim.setDuration(20); //SI PUò CONTROLLARE LA DURATA DEL LAMPEGGIO CON QUESTO PARAMETRO
              anim.setStartOffset(20);
              anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
              myButton.startAnimation(anim);
              anim.setRepeatCount(5);  

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  PreferitiActivity.class);
                //    i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                   startActivity(i);  

        }
    });

      final Button BT1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
        ViewTreeObserver vto1 = BT1.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto1.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                LayerDrawable ld1 = (LayerDrawable)BT1.getBackground();
                ld1.setLayerInset(1,0, 0, 0, BT1.getHeight()/2);}});

     final Button BT2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
        ViewTreeObserver vto2 = BT2.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto2.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
          @Override
          public void onGlobalLayout() {
                LayerDrawable ld1 = (LayerDrawable)BT2.getBackground();
                ld1.setLayerInset(1,0, 0, 0, BT2.getHeight()/2);}});

     final Button BT3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
        ViewTreeObserver vto3 = BT3.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto3.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            LayerDrawable ld1 = (LayerDrawable)BT3.getBackground();
            ld1.setLayerInset(1,0, 0, 0, BT3.getHeight()/2);}});  

   [.........omissis]
     final Button BT16 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonP);
        ViewTreeObserver vto16 = BT16.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto16.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
        LayerDrawable ld1 = (LayerDrawable)BT16.getBackground();
        ld1.setLayerInset(1,0, 0, 0, BT16.getHeight()/2);}});
```

}

}
The LogCat is this: (excuse me but i never used it before)

```
 09-09 17:02:54.160: W/dalvikvm(21991): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught 
     exception         (group=0x41476930)
09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
start           activity ComponentInfo     
  {com.wikibuyers.aforismi/com.wikibuyers.
                                        java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=48; 
 index=48
 09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991):   at   
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
 09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991):   at
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity  
  (ActivityThread.java:2230)
  09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991):
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
   09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991):     
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage 
(Handler.java:99)
09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main  
(ActivityThread.java:5039)
09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native  
Method)
09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke  
(Method.java:511)
09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991):    at   
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main  
(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991): Caused by:   
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=48; index=48
09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991):    at   
com.wikibuyers.aforismi.RandomActivity.onCreate  
(RandomActivity.java:1022)
09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate 
(Activity.java:5104)
09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991):    at   
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991):    at   
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-09 17:02:54.223: E/AndroidRuntime(21991):    ... 11 more
09-09 17:03:32.918: D/AndroidRuntime(22223): Shutting down VM
09-09 17:03:32.918: W/dalvikvm(22223): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception   
(group=0x41476930)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   
activity ComponentInfo{com.wikibuyers.aforismi/com.wikibuyers.aforismi.PreferitiActivity}:   
java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    at   
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    at   
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600 
(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage 
(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage  
(Handler.java:99)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main  
(ActivityThread.java:5039)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native  
Method)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke   
(Method.java:511)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    at   
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main 
(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename   
(ContextImpl.java:1963)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput  
(ContextImpl.java:692)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput  
(ContextWrapper.java:167)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    at  
com.wikibuyers.aforismi.PreferitiActivity.onCreate(PreferitiActivity.java:49)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate 
(Activity.java:5104)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    at  
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    at  
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-09 17:03:32.942: E/AndroidRuntime(22223):    ... 11 more
09-09 17:03:57.676: I/Process(22223): Sending signal. PID: 22223 SIG: 9
09-09 17:03:57.981: D/OpenGLRenderer(22275): Enabling debug mode 0
09-09 17:04:04.801: D/AndroidRuntime(22275): Shutting down VM
09-09 17:04:04.801: W/dalvikvm(22275): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception  
(group=0x41476930)
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  
activity ComponentInfo{com.wikibuyers.aforismi/com.wikibuyers.aforismi.PreferitiActivity}:   
java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):    at  
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):    at  
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600 
(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage 
(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage  
(Handler.java:99)
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main 
(ActivityThread.java:5039)
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native   
Method)
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke 
(Method.java:511)
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):    at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main  
(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):    at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename  
(ContextImpl.java:1963)
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput  
(ContextImpl.java:692)
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput  
(ContextWrapper.java:167)
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):    at  
com.wikibuyers.aforismi.PreferitiActivity.onCreate(PreferitiActivity.java:49)
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate  
(Activity.java:5104) 
 09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):   at  
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):    at   
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-09 17:04:04.817: E/AndroidRuntime(22275):    ... 11 more
09-09 17:04:04.832: D/dalvikvm(22275): GC_CONCURRENT freed 350K, 4% free 9283K/9664K, paused  
2ms+4ms, total 23ms
```

Activity PreferitiActivity.java is this:

```
          package com.wikibuyers.aforismi;

 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
 import java.io.Reader;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.Writer;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;


 public class PreferitiActivity extends Activity{

 public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.provare.MESSAGE";



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
      setContentView(R.layout.preferiti);


      Intent intent = getIntent();
      String message = intent.getStringExtra(SingolaFraseSelezionataActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);


      Writer writer = null;

        try {
            //FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);

            // SPOSTA IL SALVATAGGIO DEL FILE IN PREFERITI IN MODO DA AVERE SALVATAGGIO E LETTURA 
            // INSIEME E DA QUI MANDA SOLO LA FRASE AI PREFERITI

            writer = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(message,
                    MODE_PRIVATE));  //SE NON VA APPEND TORNIAMO A PRIVATE
            writer.write(message);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Frase aggiunta ai Preferiti", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

              catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Aforismi", "Impossibile salvare il file", e);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Errore", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } finally {
                    if (writer != null) {
                        try {
                            writer.close();
                        } catch (Throwable t) {
                        }
                    }
                }

      Reader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(message));

            StringBuffer aux = new StringBuffer();

            char[] buf = new char[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = reader.read(buf)) != -1) {
                aux.append(buf, 0, len);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            message = "";

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("FileDemo", "Impossibile aprire il file", e);
            message = "";

        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                }
            }
        }

        ArrayList<String> FrasiAggiuntePreferiti = new ArrayList<String>();

        FrasiAggiuntePreferiti.add(message);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item, FrasiAggiuntePreferiti);

          ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView3);
          listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
}
```

Comment: What is name "Preferiti" in your code? There is a button which name you have "Preferiti"? And instead of using "getApplicationContext()" you can use ActivityName.this

Comment: Thank you @daro. Yes it is declared as "ImageButton Preferiti = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonPreferiti);"

Comment: @daro getApplicationContext() must be used here because we are in a inner class and if i post .this give me an error message on eclipse

Comment: Please give all code for class where you have "Preferiti.setOnClickListener... " and not necessary you have use "getApplicationContext()"

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error or what?

Comment: Error message is on the phone and is "L'applicazione ... si è arrestata in modo anomalo" in italian. In English I think is an ANR message if is not so please correct me.

Comment: @all Excuse me for retarding post but I had troubles with publishing the long activity code.

Comment: Please look at (and share) the output from logcat

Comment: @Booger I have post logcat above, thanks

Comment: You have posted the wrong section of your logcat (this one is complaining about in-compatible signatures when reinstalling the app).  Look at the logcat (available from command-line by typing: adb logcat).  Monitor it when you click you button and see issue (we still don't have logcat data we need).

Comment: I posted the right LogCat I hope thanks everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is something to do with an Array out of bounds:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=48;
```

From what I can tell, this is happenning at line: 2180 of your ActivityThread class.

Bottom line, you have a logic error in your code, which is stopping your Activity from starting up successfully.  Fix your Arrary "off by 1" error, and you should be set.

Comment: I'm trying to understand it. When I'll come to a solution I'll let you Know, thanks

Comment: I don't understand where is this error in the array, could you please tell me more exactily?

Comment: You will need to debug the code yourself.  Look at the stacktrace (in the output from logcat), it will point to the line number in the class where your problem is.

Comment: Ok but I don't understand what line can be such an high number as 2180, hi don't have 2180 lines in my activities, so I would understand how I must link this number to e real code line. You're very kind and patient :-)

Answer (score 0):

do you get the exception on button click? if so check your activity start code

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PreferitiActivity.class);
 startActivity(i);
```

otherwise i guess from reading your error message you must define activity c in your manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.wikibuyers.aforismi.C" >
```

**EDIt**
you've got an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, you have lists, arrays that you didn't post and they are causing the problem... cheers :)

Comment: thanks. As I said I have all activities good declared in the manifest. I post code:      <activity      android:name=".PreferitiActivity"
          
           android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
         android:launchMode="singleInstance">
      
      </activity>

Comment: Error message is on the phone and is "L'applicazione ... si è arrestata in modo anomalo" in italian. In English I think is an ANR message if is not so please correct me.

Comment: Traducing litteral is "The application has arrested in a anomalus way". I run app directly on the phone because of problems with emulator. But it's compiled without errors in fact I can install it on the phone.

Comment: do u take the apk and install it yourself? enable debugging mode and your mobile and run the app from eclipse while your mobile is connected, logcat will give you an idea of whats happening

Comment: I must to be more clear, perhaps: my app run normally, only when I call activity C it stops and return to last working activity. I have posted logcat above, after activity A, in mode you suggest me in debug mode phone usb connected

Comment: you've got an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and i cant find any arrays, lists in your code

Comment: Youre right. Arrays are in the PreferityActivity. Now I search for error(s) and post the result and the activity. I didn'n post it for lack of space. Now I erase something unuseful and add activity.

Comment: if it works let me edit my asnwer with the right comment and accept it :) and you're welcomed

Answer (score 0):

I must close this discussion because of a change in my stategy. I have understood I should better use a database for my aims so I'll rewrite my app.
Thanks to all for their precious answers.